# Removing array elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

Am doing some jquery task which include validation of textbox which are placed in a array.
    If any of the textbox values are not filled the pop up is displayed along with the textbox name.
    Here the am facing a problem, if i delete any  textbox which are placed in the array the array is not showing the last textbox elements which are not deleted.
    Please any one who come across the same problem please assist me to solve this problem.

```
 var dynTextBoxL = $("#dynamicdiv").children().length;
    if(dynTextBoxL>0 ){
                       for(i = 0; i <= dynTextBoxL; i++){
                       var icValue = i;
                       var iV = i;
                          var checkEmpty =  $('#textbox'+iV).val();
                       $.trim(checkEmpty);
                    if(checkEmpty == ""){
                           textBoxValue.push("Spool Name "+icValue+</br>");

                        }               
                       }
```

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors. You are missing a bracket at the end. Also in the line where you push to the array, you messed up the string concatenation:

```
var dynTextBoxL = $("#dynamicdiv").children().length;
if (dynTextBoxL > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i <= dynTextBoxL; i++) {
        var icValue = i;
        var iV = i;
        var checkEmpty = $('#textbox' + iV).val();
        $.trim(checkEmpty);
        if (checkEmpty == "") {
            //was: textBoxValue.push("Spool Name "+icValue+</br>");
            textBoxValue.push("Spool Name " + icValue + "<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i delete the any textbox items in an array it gets deleted while reading the rest its also red and last array elements is skipped thats the problem am facing what to do for that